# Repeating Quantum Phase Estimation algorithm

Tags: circuit-construction, quantum-phase-estimation

In the [Quantum Recommendation Systems paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.08675.pdf), the authors use the Quantum Phase Estimation algorithm in a way that is slightly different from what I've seen so far.

This is how it is described:

> The analysis of phase estimation shows that the algorithm outputs a discrete valued estimate for each eigenvalue that is within additive error $\varepsilon$ with probability at least $0.8$, the probability is boosted to $1 − 1/\mathrm{poly}(n)$ by repeating $O(\log n)$ times and choosing the most frequent estimate.

Given that if we choose an additional number of qubits equal to $3$, the probability that the QPE outputs the correct state is $\frac{11}{12}\approx0.91$, I can use this number of qubits to implement the QPE. The problem is that I have to measure the state to store it in classical memory and thereafter re-building the most frequent one. Hence, I have to reset the output state to $|0\rangle^{\otimes t}$ to apply it once again. But from the no-deleting theorem, I cannot apply some unitary that will map this arbitrary state to $|0\rangle^{\otimes t}$. I can't either use the uncompute trick because of the measurement.

My idea was, since I know the state this register is currently in, I can add $X$ gates wherever a qubit is in the $|1\rangle$ state. But this means that I would have to add gates in the circuit "at runtime", that is:

- Performing QPE
- Measuring state
- Apply X gates accordingly
- Repeat

Is it realistic? If it is not, what other options do I have to perform such a computation?